# pandas resample to a fixed datetime

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Resample works great for me to upsample rows between two times.

E.g. with a time series (ts) like:

```
_time                  num
2018-04-11 07:55:00    1
2018-04-11 07:59:00    1
```

I can run:

```
ts.resample('min').sum().fillna(0)
```

And get:

```
_time                  num
2018-04-11 07:55:00    1
2018-04-11 07:56:00    0
2018-04-11 07:57:00    0
2018-04-11 07:58:00    0
2018-04-11 07:59:00    1
```

However, I want to resample until midnight no matter what, instead of resampling to the last row in the series.

E.g. final output to be:

```
_time                  num
2018-04-11 07:55:00    1
2018-04-11 07:56:00    0
2018-04-11 07:57:00    0
2018-04-11 07:58:00    0
2018-04-11 07:59:00    1
...
2018-04-11 23:58:00    0
2018-04-11 23:59:00    0
2018-04-12 00:00:00    0
```

One solution is just to add a row to the series where _time is midnight and num is 0.

However, is there a more elegant built-in solution?

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: @Scotty1- I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: So do you want to fill your DataFrame from `2018-04-11 07:59:00` until `2018-04-12 00:00:00` with zeros or do you have and other values than those in your timeseries `ts` that you want to interpolate/mean/etc.?

Comment: I want to fill all those minutes with zeros

Comment: Also the minutes between `2018-04-11 07:55:00` and `2018-04-11 07:59:00`?

Comment: If yes, then I am sorry. Afaik there is no more elegant built-in solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no built-in solution to reach a desired end point with `resample` like *midnight* (AFAIK), consider a dynamic solution to add the row based on current *ts* data using `pd.concat` on a single-value, calculated  *midnight* series.

Specifically, the *midnight* series is built by taking the `max` index value of *ts* and normalizing it to midnight and then add 1 day using datetime's `timedelta()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

ts = pd.Series([1,0,0,0,1], name = 'num',
               index = pd.date_range('2018-04-11 07:55:00', periods=5, freq='min')).rename_axis('_time')

# NORMALIZE AND THEN ADD 1 DAY
midnight = pd.Series([np.nan], name = 'num',
                     index = [max(ts.index).normalize() + dt.timedelta(days=1)]).rename_axis('_time')

# CONCATENATE BOTH SERIES AND THEN RESAMPLE
final_ts = pd.concat([ts, midnight]).resample('min').sum().fillna(0)

print(final_ts.head())
# _time
# 2018-04-11 07:55:00    1.0
# 2018-04-11 07:56:00    0.0
# 2018-04-11 07:57:00    0.0
# 2018-04-11 07:58:00    0.0
# 2018-04-11 07:59:00    1.0
# Freq: T, Name: num, dtype: float64

print(final_ts.tail())
# _time
# 2018-04-11 23:56:00    0.0
# 2018-04-11 23:57:00    0.0
# 2018-04-11 23:58:00    0.0
# 2018-04-11 23:59:00    0.0
# 2018-04-12 00:00:00    0.0
# Freq: T, Name: num, dtype: float64
```